# 入れ子のURLパラメータ取得方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

以下のURLから、lowを取得したいのですが、方法の分かる方がいましたらご教授お願い致します。

URL：http://100.100.100.100/test/site/page/1?money%5Bgo_to%5D=low

また、取得する箇所はbefore_save内になります。

下記は検証済みの取得コードです。いずれも動きませんでした。
params[:money.go_to]
params[:money][:go_to]

Comment: `p params` するとデータ構造見れたような記憶がありますが、どうでしょう？

Answer (score 1):

`before_save`がモデルのコールバックのことを言っているのであれば、そこからは`params`は参照できません。

モデルにはデータベースのカラムと対応しない属性も定義できます。コントローラでparamsから値を取り出し、それ経由で値を渡すようにするとよいでしょう。データベースに保存されないのを除き、データベースのカラムに対応する属性とほぼ扱いは変わりません。

```
class User < ...
  attribute :hoge
end

@user = User.new
user.hoge = params[:money][:go_to]
```